# Anova with count data: glm?

Tags: r, glm, anova

I have this kind of data:

> y: count data 
> x: a factorial predictor with 3 levels

Conceptually I need an ANOVA testing if the means of `y` for the three levels (`group`) are significantly different.
Due to the `y` is a count I performed a poisson `glm` like this (in R):

```
y (count) ~ glm(x, family=poisson)
```

and then? How can I proceede?
I need to know if level `1` is significantly different from `2` and `3` and if `2` is significantly different from `3` (all the possible combinations).

Thanks

Comment: Similar to linear regression; fit the null model (intercept only), then fit your model with predictor x and test the change in deviance with anova(null , fullmodel , test="Chisq")

Comment: And then use the multcomp package to do the pair-wise comparisons.

Comment: Ok, what suggest user20650 is the same to do Anova(fullmodel) with the package Car. Then I need a pair-wise comparisons. Roland can you suggest me a suitable function in the package multcomp? I don't usually use it.

Comment: The pairwise comparisons can be done by changing the reference level of the factor X in your glm call. Or using glht in multcomp will allow for more complex hypothesis to be tested.

Comment: How can I "change the reference level of the factor X in my glm call"? Thanks

Comment: Say to compare factor level 2 to level 3; you can change the reference level to 2 by factor(x,levels(2,1,3)). If you want to compare level 1 to both 2 and 3 together you can use I(x==1)

Comment: If you do what @user20650 suggests, you'll need to manually adjust p-values for alpha error inflation.

Comment: alternatively what do you suggest?

Comment: Use the change in deviance to test for differences in the means but for all pairwise comparisons use glht in the multcomp package. @Roland is of course correct over adjusting p-values - although I am generally lass conservative over adjusting for multiple tests

Comment: I finally decided to use a quasipoisson error distribution to deal with overdispersion. The model is now: model <- y ~ glm(x, family=quasipoisson). Then I succeed to apply glht in this way: glht <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(x = "Tukey")) and obtained the pairwise comparisons. My question is: are these p value corrected for a glm quasi poisson? If x would be continuous I would have asked for p value like this Anova(model, test="F"). –

Comment: I am not sure - this is probably a question for Crossvalidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/). I don't think using Anova would be correct as it is not a real likelihood. Did you try a negative binomial dist?